Nested if or some kind of nested condition in OPA rule engine
I am new to OPA rule engine and have tried a few things out, I am unable to write a nested if in opa rule engine like
output := someValue if {
     someValue := someOtherValue if {

     }
}

I know the above lines are wrong, I just want to understand if someone wants to try a nested condition what they need to do, are there different keywords or some different design strategies we need to follow?

Yes we can write conditions. Lets take look at simple example Suppose we want to allow access if:
input.some_value is "hello" AND
input.some_other_value is "world" AND
Based on the user's name: AND
  If input.user is "bob", then my_value should be "foo" OR
  If input.user is "john", then my_value should be "bar"

We can write rego policy for this as below
package play

import rego.v1
default allow=false

allow if{
   input.some_value="hello"
   input.some_other_value="world"
   my_value=my_value
}

my_value= result if{
   input.user="bob"
   result="foo"
}

my_value= result if{
   input.user="john"
   result="bar"
}

Here is playground link you can try https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/lvZmvs6pWL
